# Issuing bitcoin-cli commands via terminal

Tags: json-rpc, bitcoin-cli

I am having issues utilizing bitcoin-cli via terminal. For example:

`DIRECT-8A-HP-OfficeJet-4650:~ peter$ bitcoin-cli deriveaddresses "wpkh(xpub6Dy2ikUu5mXbDdhw2vAP1C4eiQM8rTz1NiWQt2BzGi83iHC2gEgTSD54JveyuHF9VLAqNkCGnee1jdBL7nA3JNorbqjSSS8DEV6Hn3PuNBt/*)#mn5jvyc3" 99
error code: -8
error message:
Range must be specified as end or as [begin,end]
DIRECT-8A-HP-OfficeJet-4650:~ peter$`

However the exact same text in the Bitcoin Core console works without issue.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you running bitcoin-cli on a printer?

Comment: Haha, no, I have to disguise the hotspot I create at work.. I am living under harsh conditions ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution, just use curl in the terminal which communicates the commands via binary data.